# Proof of implicit function theorem in Hartman's ODE Book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Implicit function theorem in hartmann ode book

Let $x,y,f,g$ be d-dimensional vectors and $z$ an e-dimensional vector. Let $f(y,z)$ be contionuous for $(y,z)$ near a point $(y_0,z_0)$ and have continuous partial derivatives with respect to the components of $y$. Let the jacobian $\det\partial f^j/\partial y^k\neq 0$ at $(y,z)=(y_0,z_0)$. Let $x_0=f(y_0,z_0)$ then there exist positive numbers, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, such that if $x$ and $z$ are fixed, $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $|z-z_0|<\delta$, then the equation $x=f(y,z)$ has a unique solution $y=g(x,z)$ satisfying $|y-y_0|<\epsilon$. further has continuous partial derivatives with respect to the components of $x$.

Actually I understand implicit function theorem in Munkres analysis on manifold. but above theorem only assume continuous partial derivative with respect to y. in Munkres case, they assume f is differentiable, I'm having a hard time even figuring out how to start the proof.

Please give me some help how to prove above theorem.

Comment: As usual, you use the simplified Newton method $y_{n+1}=y_n-A(f(y_n,z)-x)$ with $A$ the inverse of $(∂f^j/∂y^k)_{jk}$ as fixed-point iteration and select the radii so that it is contracting. Then apply the Banach fixed-point theorem.

Comment: Thanks your answer, I'll try the method you suggested.

Comment: Sorry it's to hard to me prove this theorem. In my reference , we need $f$ is $C_1$  on the neighborhood $(y_0,z_0)$ to apply implicit function theorem, but In Hartman's book, only define $f$ has continuous derivative for "$y$ component"and actually, the conclusion is also different in my reference (spivak "calculus on manifold", munkres "analysis on manifold"). Is there any other reference which has the same form of "implicit function theorem" in my question?

Comment: In my reference, to prove "implicit function theorem", we use inverse function theorem. and to prove inverse function theorem they use "contraction mapping"  (actually in munkres, they use other way).

Comment: Yes, the claims of both IFT are equivalent if using the stricter assumptions. This may not work for the claim here with the weaker assumption of only a partial differentiability, as it appears to be the case. This would be equivalent to an inverse function theorem for block-triangular systems where only the diagonal blocks are differentiable.